# How does one create a record, based on custom provided key and value data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures, reduce

I'm still a beginner in JavaScript and I need to create an object based on what the user types in the input fields.

Here are the input fields on my form:

[image]

After the user enters the values for column and value, this is how the data is being received:

```js
[
  [{
      label: "Column",
      value: "column1",
      name: "01",
    },
    {
      label: "Value",
      value: "value1",
      name: "02",
    },
  ],
  [{
      label: "Column",
      value: "column2",
      name: "10",
    },
    {
      label: "Value",
      value: "value2",
      name: "11",
    },
  ],
];
```

But that's not how it can be saved to send the database, the way I need to send it is like this:

```js
{
  // other data
  
  "column_names": {
    "column1": "value1",
    "column2": "value2"
  }
}
```

Could you tell me how can I create an Object based on what the user types? But in the structure I showed in the second code snippet?

Comment: Where's your code? We can't debug code if we can't see it.

Comment: it's better to add the code that you are using to save the inputs values, this way it is easier to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure provided by the OP can be seen as an array of object entries where each entry holds a tuple of key and value related meta data.

Thus a straightforward approach does [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the provided data into the desired record.

```js
const receivedData = [
  [{
    label: "Column",
    value: "column1",
    name: "01",
  }, {
    label: "Value",
    value: "value1",
    name: "02",
  }], [{
    label: "Column",
    value: "column2",
    name: "10",
  }, {
    label: "Value",
    value: "value2",
    name: "11",
  }],
];

const recordData = {

  // other data

  "column_names": receivedData
    .reduce((data, [ keyData, valueData ]) => {
      const key = keyData.value;
      const { value } = valueData;
      return Object.assign(data, { [key]: value });
    }, {})
};
console.log({ recordData });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Peter, that's works perfectly for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

your expected result is object design based where you can group value by their names which is a bit more lengthy but if you wanted to improve object design to do same task i have a suggested code try this

use `data` attribute on input fields with their name
then get all the values in one object with their corresponding key names see an example below

```js
function getData(root){
    const Els = root.querySelectorAll("[data]"),newOb = {}
    Els.forEach(each=>{
        let key = each.getAttribute("data"), val = each.value
        newOb[key] = val
    })
    return newOb            
}
const main = document.querySelector(".root")
main.oninput = function(){console.log(getData(main))}
```

```html
<div class="root">
    <input class="border" data="col1" type="text">
    <input class="border" data="col2" type="text">
    <input class="border" data="col3" type="text">
    <input class="border" data="col4" type="text">
</div>
```